# Python 3 - CSV and cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, csv, cx-oracle

I'm having some serious trouble working with the csv and cx_oracle module. I want to read a csv file, that is saved in UTF-8 (I checked it by saving it with Notepad in UTF-8). I can read everything fine now (before I saved it as UTF-8 it didn't). This is my code to read the csv-file:

```
 with open(file, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    csvinput = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
    for row in csvinput:
        data.append(row)
```

This saves everything to a 2D array. 
Whenever I want to insert something into the database, I make a preparedstatement, and load the text into it as such:

```
data = [lastname, firstname]
cursor = cx_Oracle.Cursor(connection)
cursor.prepare("SELECT * FROM PRIVATE WHERE NAME = :1 AND FIRSTNAME = :2")
cursor.execute(None, data)
res = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
```

It gives me tons of errors like:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried reading up on the whole thing, but I got rather confused with the unicode thing as I don't really know where I should use what and why...
Any help is appreciated.
**TLDR** I get encoding errors whilst trying to execute prepared statements

Comment: Show the traceback. Which line is generating the error?

Comment: the cursor.execute is giving me the error (cursor.execute(None, data))

Comment: What is the schema for the `PRIVATE` table? What column types did you use?

Comment: The column types are VARCHAR2

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert Unicode values into a `VARCHAR2` column, which can only handle encoded byte strings.

cx_Oracle is trying to encode your Unicode values for you to fit the column type, and does so with the default codec for your connection.

Either encode your values to a suitable encoding manually or make your columns use `NVARCHAR2` instead.

The latter has the added advantage that column lengths are expressed in *characters*, not bytes; UTF-8 data can use up to 4 bytes per character, so a `VARCHAR2(1000)` column could, in a worst-case scenario, fit only 250 actual characters.

Comment: How can I do the first solution you suggest? And how do I see the correct encoding method I should use?

Comment: I tried this 
for row in csvinput:
            for cell in row:
                cell = str.encode(cell, encoding = 'iso-8859-1')
But that's not working either...

Comment: Oracle is particularly difficult about encodings. You'll have to set the [`NLS_LANG` environment parameter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html) to match the codec you are using, I think. But using `VARCHAR2` for encoded unicode text has enormous drawbacks, not least that it makes querying for specific string values really hard.